# Help required to prove a question on triangles, collinearity and cyclic quadrilaterls

Tags: geometry, triangles

In an acute $\triangle ABC$ $D,E,F$ are feet of perpendiculars from $A,B,C$ respectively. The perpendiculars from $F$ to $BC,AD,CA,BE$ intersect them at $X,Y,Z,V$.

How do I prove that $X,Y,Z,V$ are collinear points?[image]

Comment: Could you provide a figure, even drawn by hand ?

Comment: Please provide a rough sketck

Comment: @JeanMarie Forgive for late response,now it is there.

Comment: @Narasimham Forgive for late response,now it is there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$F$ is a point on the circumcircle of $BEC$, hence $X,V,Z$ are collinear
by [Simson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simson_line).

On the other hand, $F$ also belongs to the circumcircle of $ADC$, hence $X,Y,Z$ are collinear, too.

[image]

Comment: From which book would you suggest me to study geometry, which include advance topics such as **Simson line**

Comment: @Ayushakj: do you already know www.cut-the-knot.org? If not, it is worth to start an exploration, even a chaotic one.